# How to get security groups not yet assigned to an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have the following method:

```
public String createGroup( String groupName, String description, String vpcId ) {
    logger.debug( "Create Group called");
    CreateSecurityGroupRequest sgrReq = new CreateSecurityGroupRequest();
    sgrReq.setGroupName(groupName);
    sgrReq.setDescription(description);
    sgrReq.setVpcId(vpcId);

    CreateSecurityGroupResult csgRes = ec2Client.createSecurityGroup(sgrReq );
    String groupId = csgRes.getGroupId();
    logger.debug( "Security Group '{}', with ID {}, created in VPC '{}'", groupName, groupId, vpcId);

    return groupId;
}
```

It creates a security group, which I can see when I go the EC2 console for security groups.  I have not yet assigned the group to an EC2 instance via `ec2Client.modifyInstanceAttribute`.   What service/method of the AWS SDK would I use to list back all security groups, even those not yet assigned to any instances?  To be explicit, ec2Client.getEc2Instance(ec2Id).getSecurityGroups() does not work, since the group has not yet been assigned to an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DescribeSecurityGroups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSecurityGroups.html) API without applying any [filter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_Filter.html).

Comment: Looks like that's what I need.  The Javadoc is at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/SdkForJava/ec2-2016-11-15/DescribeSecurityGroups, it returns a DescribeSecurityGroupsResult which has a getSecurityGroups method.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeSecurityGroupsResult.html#getSecurityGroups--